# C++ Program Printing 0 When Numbers Too Large

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that prints the factorial of a number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int ans,fact=1, number;
    cin>>number;

    for (int i=1; i<=number; i++) {
        fact = fact*i;
    }
    ans = fact%998244353;
    cout <<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to input the number 250, the program returns 0, but when I try to print a smaller number like 4, it returns the right number. Does anyone know why this occurs and how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: C++ `int` can only store a certain amount of data. It's not infinite. You can use `long` or `long long` to get more space, but if you need truly unbounded space, you'll need a bigint library like gmp.

Comment: When I try to use long long, the program still returns 0.

Comment: Factorial grows quite fast and overflows integer. 20! is biggest value which fits into 64 bits.

Comment: What is the *real* purpose of this program? To ring `number! % 998244353` ? If so, you need to understand a technique called modulo chaining (little google term there), which says `(a * b) % c` is equivalent to `((a % c) * (b % c)) % c`. Now think about how you can utilize that to retool that loop.

Comment: 64-bit integer (like usual `long long`) can only store numbers up to about 10^18. That's means at most `20!`. The task is about using modular arithmetic to reach the result, not just about multiplying a number in a loop.

Comment: Yes, `250!` is a nearly 500-digit number. That's 10^500, or around 2^1636, i.e. 200 bytes of data. `int` normally stores around 4 bytes, and `long long` normally stores around 8. So you're not even in the ballpark.

Comment: If you are asked to compute `250! % 998244353`, then the point of the problem is not to implement the expression into a program. The point of the question is to do some math to modify the expression into a form that is easier to handle for a computer. It is not about being able to program or learning to program, but knowing or practicing math.

Comment: Can you explain your task with more detials? This `fact%998244353;` indicates that you have to do something different then just calculating a factorial.

Comment: The task was just, "Please use recursion to find the value of 1*2*3*...*n

modulo 998244353"

Comment: Then, as WhozCraig pointed out, the trick is modulo chaining. Google it and read about it. You've fallen into the exact trap that whoever wrote this assignment or challenge *wanted* you to fall into by trying to directly compute the expression as written.

Comment: just do modulo every step and problem solved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: [See example here](https://godbolt.org/z/v41qKdK3n).

Comment: In the future, it might help to explain, in words, the goal of your program in addition to showing the code. I didn't notice the modulo at the end until it was pointed out, and even if I had I would've dismissed it as a vain attempt to fix a broken factorial program. Knowing that this is a modular arithmetic problem, my advice about gmp is ill-placed.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints for doing math in a finite field or ring while avoiding overflow.

Mathematically is true that:

`(a*b)%c == ((a%c)*(b%c))%c`

and also:

`(a+b)%c == ((a%c)+(b%c))%c`

But in the case a*b or a+b will overflow, you have to use the righthand expression because it is less likely to overflow.